# MDX display months of days

Tags: mdx, days

I have a time dimension (Year-Month-Day) which must perform the filter of information by a date range (eg 03/16/2014 to 05/18/2014) and demonstrate the values ​​of the measures by month name and how many days are part of the account..

```
WITH 
SET [Periodo]         AS ([Data.YMD].[2014].[3].[16]:[Data.YMD].[2014].[5].[18])
MEMBER [Measures].[Days]     AS 'COUNT([Periodo])'
SELECT 
NON EMPTY 
{
    Descendants([Periodo] , [Data.YMD].[Mes].level, AFTER )  <<---- not working
} ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY {
    [Measures].[Amount],
    [Measures].[Days],
} ON ROWS
FROM [FluxoCaixa]
```

Comment: What is your question? What is the result you get? What is the result you expect?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0UL0-6YseY8a1NqU2ItTWx3MjQ/edit?(usp=sharing), see here what i need, is the middle image

Comment: this clause with this problem, when you compress and then expands back to show missing values ​​is not only the sum of the values ​​of the days of the month, but every day of the month.

Comment: special note: i use mondrian in pentaho analysis

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to show just the months belonging to the days in set `[Periodo]` in the columns, but not the days themselves? Should `[Measures].[Days]` be the number of days contained in `[Periodo]`, the number of days in each month shown in the columns, or the number of days contained in `[Periodo]` and the month shown on the column?